# Clock jitter - ppm, ui, ps

Tags: clock, xilinx, pll, jitter

I using Xilinx FPGA and need to use its PLL (MMCM or Clk Wizard)
I have on my board LVDS 200MHz clock with 50 ppm frequency jitter,
I took this and go to some converted I can find on the internet and I can see that 50 ppm from 200 MHz is a frequency variation of 10 kHz:
[image]

OK so I look at my PLL and there I need to insert the jitter value in units of PS or UI.
How I can convert it to these units? I can't find it in the PLL documentation from Xilinx.

Comment: 50 ppm perhaps is not jitter, but the steady state frequency tolerance for initial error at 25'C, You can buy 1 or 2 ppm temperature compensated crystal oscillators pretty cheap. Define what you need.  f, temp range and why jitter?  You could use  VCXO with desired control range and correct f or inject jitter with some low f according to some reference. What is UI > User Interface <?>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "Good News" first: I can save you using an online calculator.

"ppm" is for "parts per million"; so 50 ppm simply means a relative error of 50·10⁻⁶; at 200 MHz, that means 200·10⁶ Hz · 50·10⁻⁶ = 10000 Hz. It's that simple!

Bad news:

Doesn't have anything to do with jitter.

Your clock could be running at, say 200.010 MHz (which is just *barely* within the error specified by the ppm accuracy) perfectly stable – and have zero jitter.

Or it could be running at an average of 200.000000 MHz, but make random phase jumps at arbitrary times and have a gigantic jitter.

Your specification of ppm describes an overall accuracy. As in "when you use this oscillator, its frequency is going to be within nominal frequency +- x ppm".

What it doesn't tell you at all is how much the oscillator varies within that range during use.

But jitter is just that: how much does the point at which, for example, we observe a positive-going zero crossing, change. How much does it jump around?

You'll need a different specification than just for the overall accuracy.

Typically, the specification you're looking for is "phase noise over frequencies", or "Allan variance"/"Allan deviation", both from which you can calculate the *energy* of the phase noise, which is essentially the variance of jittering, and that's the square of the standard deviation of jitter; it's its RMS value.

For more in-depth "how to phase noise to jitter": This [analog devices tutorial](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-008.pdf) seems appropriate.

For "how to Allan variance to jitter": Bigger topic, I think if you have an oscillator device that specifies Allan deviation/variance instead of phase noise, you'd probably have to understand the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_variance) on the topic, anyway, so if that's the case, I'd encourage you to ask a new question describing where your 200 MHz come from, what you're doing with them and your PLL's frequency and so on.